# how to find out is a long string contatins a word obj c, iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, compare

I have a long string that has a running list of all the "words entered" in the text box.
I want to be able to check the long string against a one word string to see if the long string contains the word in the short string.

Any ideas?

I've tried this and a few other things, where newString is the long string and currentTextrightnow is the short string.

```
textRange =[newString rangeOfString:currentTextrightnow];
NSLog(@"currenttextright now is %@", currentTextrightnow);
if(textRange.location != NSNotFound)

{

    NSLog(@"Does contatin the substring");

}
```

Comment: what you are doing should be good enough. is there any problem?

Comment: Yes the problem is it always returns true no matter what i put in.

Comment: Have you made sure that `newString` isn't `nil`?

Comment: @Wevah Yeah I've tried printing it out...I just don't know what the issue is. Can anyone suggest alternative methods?

Comment: If what you're doing isn't working, you should figure out why and fix it. I don't see a problem with what you've written.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem as you did. You are actually doing it right (if textRange is of type NSRange) but the problem is NSNotFound doesn't work as expected (might be a bug). Instead you can do

```
if (range.length > 0) {
    //it found it
} else {
    // it didn't find it
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I just looked back at this after about 3 years. My apologies about not marking that it was correct. Back then I didn't know exactly how to use Stack Overflow