# is a character already in the range?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I need to get, is a character already in the range. The character string is of type NSMuttableString. 
For example, I have a string of "52.648" and I need to know is a "." symbol is already in the string. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [rangeOfString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSString) message on the NSString:

```
NSRange rng = [string rangeOfString:@"."];
if (rng.location != NSNotFound)
    // "." is in the string at position rng.location
```

Comment: Just an addition. I used this and even with a heap of NSLogs confirming correct data NSNotFound didn't work as expected. The link below has a solution IF you have this problem.

Comment: @Rudiger Thanks man. I checked out the linked answer and up-voted it :)

Answer (score 1):

The following expression is true if and only if myChar is within myString:

```
[myString rangeOfString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%c", myChar]
                options: NULL].location != NSNotFound
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as addition to the other answers which are correct. I've had issues using NSNotFound. Not sure if its a bug or not but using range.length > 0 works as intended. I posted about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877835/how-to-find-out-is-a-long-string-contatins-a-word-obj-c-iphone/3878896#3878896)